# Backbone multiple fetch of data at app loading?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have some backbone collections that should be loaded in my app at loading (bootstrap data).  These data are static information that are used everywhere to populate lists, drop down etc.

What is the best way to load these data and make sure they are fully loaded before my router is instantated

```
App.StaticCollections.contactTypes.fetch({}),
App.StaticCollections.documentTemplates.fetch({}),
App.StaticCollections.invoiceStatuses.fetch({}),
App.StaticCollections.estimateStatuses.fetch({}),
App.StaticCollections.currencies.fetch({})

App.Router = new MainRouter();
Backbone.history.start({
    pushState: false,
    root: App.Root
});
```

Comment: It is always a better Idea  for the static data to be always present when the page is initially loaded... Bootstrap this data to your page.. Do not fetch it on page load

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

```
$.when(
  App.StaticCollections.contactTypes.fetch({}),
  App.StaticCollections.documentTemplates.fetch({}),
  App.StaticCollections.invoiceStatuses.fetch({}),
  App.StaticCollections.estimateStatuses.fetch({}),
  App.StaticCollections.currencies.fetch({})
).then(function () {
  App.Router = new MainRouter();
  Backbone.history.start({
    pushState: false,
    root: App.Root
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To piggyback off Sushanth's comment ... in general you don't want to make multiple requests just to enable your page to render.  If there's a network delay, that can be very frustrating for the user.

Bootstrap the data to your page, using [Collection.reset](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset):

```
App.StaticCollections.contactTypes.reset([ 
    { attr1: "val1", ... }
]);
```

If appropriate, embed the values dynamically using your server-side language.

Comment: When you say, embed the values dynamically, do you mean include JSON files as a static file of the website or simply include the data inside a script tag?